# Custom menu in backend

Tags: magento-1.9

i have my custom menu of my cutom module.

I have this:

```
<menu>
   <holamundo module="holamundo">
    <title>Hola Mundo</title>
    <sort_order>71</sort_order>     
    <children>
     <items module="holamundo">
      <title>Gestionar</title>
      <sort_order>0</sort_order>
      <action>holamundo/adminhtml_web</action>
     </items>
    </children>
   </holamundo>
</menu>
```

The menu appears but when I give the submenu, I forwarded to another page where the content is blank.
Can anyone tell me how to do something to show on this page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this structure `Your/Extension/controllers/Adminhtml/Custom/WebController.php`
You have to add this line in your config.xml
`<admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Your_Extension_Adminhtml before="Mage_Adminhtml">Your_Extension_Adminhtml</Your_Extension_Adminhtml>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>`

And then your action node will be
`<action>adminhtml/custom/web</action>`

For more complexe structure, all subdirectories after `controller/Adminhtml/**/*Controller.php` is translated by and underscore between subdirectories :
`Your/Extension/controller/Adminhtml/My/Complexe/Structure/WebController.php`
will be
`<action>adminhtml/my_complexe_structure/web</action>`

For more informations about custom adminhtml routing a great article from Alan Storm : http://alanstorm.com/magento_admin_hello_world_revisited

Comment: when add? <action>adminhtml/custom/web</action>. i have my WebController.php with a lot of functions (i show a tutorial), I linked this WebController.php but the page is in white

Comment: In your menu node instead of `<action>holamundo/adminhtml_web</action>`

Comment: Yes, but the page continue in white.

Comment: In this case it is not a controller issue but a layout, I suggest you to read this article from Alan Storm : http://alanstorm.com/magento_admin_hello_world_revisited

Comment: In any case, my answer and the article from Alan Storm is the best practice for secure admin URL and custom routing. You should read it and test again from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Look my files:

config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
<Company_Holamundo>
<version>0.1.0</version>
</Company_Holamundo>
</modules>
<frontend>
<routers>
<holamundo>
<use>standard</use>
<args>
<module>Company_Holamundo</module>
<frontName>holamundo</frontName>
</args>
</holamundo>
</routers>
<layout>
<updates>
<holamundo>
<file>holamundo.xml</file>
</holamundo>
</updates>
</layout>
</frontend>
<admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Company_Holamundo_Adminhtml before="Mage_Adminhtml">Company_Holamundo_Adminhtml</Company_Holamundo_Adminhtml>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
  <menu>
   <holamundo module="holamundo">
    <title>Hola Mundo</title>
    <sort_order>71</sort_order>     
    <children>
     <items module="holamundo">
      <title>Gestionar</title>
      <sort_order>0</sort_order>
      <action>adminhtml/web</action>
     </items>

    </children>
   </holamundo>
  </menu>
  <acl>
   <resources>
    <all>
     <title>Allow Everything</title>
    </all>
    <admin>
     <children>
      <Company_Holamundo>
       <title>Holamundo</title>
       <sort_order>10</sort_order>
      </Company_Holamundo>
     </children>
    </admin>
   </resources>
  </acl>
  <layout>
   <updates>
    <holamundo>
     <file>web.xml</file>
    </holamundo>
   </updates>
  </layout>
    </adminhtml>   
<global>
<models>
<holamundo>
<class>Company_Holamundo_Model</class>
</holamundo>
</models>
<blocks>
<holamundo>
<class>Company_Holamundo_Block</class>
</holamundo>
</blocks>
        <helpers>
            <holamundo>
                <class>Company_Holamundo_Helper</class>
            </holamundo>
        </helpers>
</global>
</config>
```

And this is my WebController.php:

```
<?php

class Company_Holamundo_Adminhtml_WebController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_action
{

 protected function _initAction() {
  $this->loadLayout()
   ->_setActiveMenu('web/items')
   ->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Items Manager'), Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item Manager'));

  return $this;
 }   

 public function indexAction() {
  $this->_initAction()
   ->renderLayout();
 }

 public function editAction() {
  $id     = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
  $model  = Mage::getModel('web/web')->load($id);

  if ($model->getId() || $id == 0) {
   $data = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getFormData(true);
   if (!empty($data)) {
    $model->setData($data);
   }

   Mage::register('web_data', $model);

   $this->loadLayout();
   $this->_setActiveMenu('web/items');

   $this->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item Manager'), Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item Manager'));
   $this->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item News'), Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item News'));

   $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setCanLoadExtJs(true);

   $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('web/adminhtml_web_edit'))
    ->_addLeft($this->getLayout()->createBlock('web/adminhtml_web_edit_tabs'));

   $this->renderLayout();
  } else {
   Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('web')->__('Item does not exist'));
   $this->_redirect('*/*/');
  }
 }

 public function newAction() {
  $this->_forward('edit');
 }

 public function saveAction() {
  if ($data = $this->getRequest()->getPost()) {

   if(isset($_FILES['filename']['name']) && $_FILES['filename']['name'] != '') {
    try { 
     /* Starting upload */ 
     $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('filename');

     // Any extention would work
              $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'));
     $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);

     // Set the file upload mode 
     // false -> get the file directly in the specified folder
     // true -> get the file in the product like folders 
     // (file.jpg will go in something like /media/f/i/file.jpg)
     $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);

     // We set media as the upload dir
     $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS ;
     $uploader->save($path, $_FILES['filename']['name'] );

    } catch (Exception $e) {

          }

          //this way the name is saved in DB
      $data['filename'] = $_FILES['filename']['name'];
   }

   $model = Mage::getModel('web/web');  
   $model->setData($data)
    ->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'));

   try {
    if ($model->getCreatedTime == NULL || $model->getUpdateTime() == NULL) {
     $model->setCreatedTime(now())
      ->setUpdateTime(now());
    } else {
     $model->setUpdateTime(now());
    } 

    $model->save();
    Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('web')->__('Item was successfully saved'));
    Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setFormData(false);

    if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('back')) {
     $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $model->getId()));
     return;
    }
    $this->_redirect('*/*/');
    return;
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setFormData($data);
                $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')));
                return;
            }
        }
        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('web')->__('Unable to find item to save'));
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
 }

 public function deleteAction() {
  if( $this->getRequest()->getParam('id') > 0 ) {
   try {
    $model = Mage::getModel('web/web');

    $model->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))
     ->delete();

    Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item was successfully deleted'));
    $this->_redirect('*/*/');
   } catch (Exception $e) {
    Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
    $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')));
   }
  }
  $this->_redirect('*/*/');
 }

    public function massDeleteAction() {
        $webIds = $this->getRequest()->getParam('web');
        if(!is_array($webIds)) {
   Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Please select item(s)'));
        } else {
            try {
                foreach ($webIds as $webId) {
                    $web = Mage::getModel('web/web')->load($webId);
                    $web->delete();
                }
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(
                    Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__(
                        'Total of %d record(s) were successfully deleted', count($webIds)
                    )
                );
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
            }
        }
        $this->_redirect('*/*/index');
    }

    public function massStatusAction()
    {
        $webIds = $this->getRequest()->getParam('web');
        if(!is_array($webIds)) {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($this->__('Please select item(s)'));
        } else {
            try {
                foreach ($webIds as $webId) {
                    $web = Mage::getSingleton('web/web')
                        ->load($webId)
                        ->setStatus($this->getRequest()->getParam('status'))
                        ->setIsMassupdate(true)
                        ->save();
                }
                $this->_getSession()->addSuccess(
                    $this->__('Total of %d record(s) were successfully updated', count($webIds))
                );
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage());
            }
        }
        $this->_redirect('*/*/index');
    }

    protected function _sendUploadResponse($fileName, $content, $contentType='application/octet-stream')
    {
        $response = $this->getResponse();
        $response->setHeader('HTTP/1.1 200 OK','');
        $response->setHeader('Pragma', 'public', true);
        $response->setHeader('Cache-Control', 'must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0', true);
        $response->setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename='.$fileName);
        $response->setHeader('Last-Modified', date('r'));
        $response->setHeader('Accept-Ranges', 'bytes');
        $response->setHeader('Content-Length', strlen($content));
        $response->setHeader('Content-type', $contentType);
        $response->setBody($content);
        $response->sendResponse();
        die;
    }
}
```

Repeat, These files have a tutorial